# What is the correct age of Kali yug?

Tags: kali-yuga

I had heard earlier that Kali yug has got age of 432000 years, but some says it's a calculation mistake and Kali yug has got only 5800 years which is even less than 10,0000 years. Can someone please show me the scripts which actually describes the age of Kali yug and with correct understanding of scripts for taking calculation. Or please describe the correct age with correct calculations?

Thanks in advance!

Edited

In the suggested [answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/48669/which-scripture-mentions-yuga-length), the calculation is based on below logic/rule,

**1 Divine year = 360 Human years.**
But didn't mention the script which describes the above rule. So to be confirmed, can you please update the script for the rule, so that I will be okay with that answer.

Please provide script for each separate formula/rule.

Sir, the correct answer to this question will save my lots of my time...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Which scripture mentions Yuga length?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/48669/which-scripture-mentions-yuga-length)

Comment: current age of kali is 5124 years.. maybe someone got confused and said total age is 5800

Comment: @mar i updated my question, i think you are correct, 5124 looks correct, can you please answer my question, i will be great!

Comment: @KailashChandraPolai below answer mentions that one ayana (6months) is day and another ayana (6months) is night for Devas..so it’s simple logic right that 1 deva’s day & night = 1 human year and 1 deva’s year (containing 360 such days) = 360 human years…

Comment: @YDS yes, right

Answer (score 3):

As per [Vishnu Purana: Book I: Chapter III](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/vp/vp037.htm)

> Oh best of sages, fifteen twinklings of the eye make a Kásht́há; thirty Kásht́hás, one Kalá; and thirty Kalás, one Muhúrtta 3. Thirty Muhúrttas constitute a day and night of mortals: thirty such days make a month, divided into two half-months: **six months form an Ayana (the period of the sun's progress north or south of the ecliptic): and two Ayanas compose a year. The southern Ayana is a night, and the northern a day of the gods**.
>
> Twelve thousand divine years, each composed of (three hundred and sixty) such days, constitute the period of the four Yugas, or ages. They are thus distributed: the Krita age has four thousand divine years; the Tretá three thousand; the Dwápara two thousand; and the **Kali age one thousand**: so those acquainted with antiquity have declared. The period that precedes a Yuga is called a **Sandhyá**, and it is of as many **hundred years as there are thousands** in the Yuga: and the period that follows a Yuga, termed the **Sandhyánsa**, is of similar duration.

So, total period of Kaliyuga would be **1200 divine years** (1000 divine years' Kaliyuga + 100 divine years' Sandhyá + 100 divine years' Sandhyánsa)

In human years, it would be 1200 divine years * 360 = **432000 human years**

---

The same chapter further says:

> The Krita, Tretá, Dwápara, and Kali, constitute a great age, or aggregate of four ages: a thousand such aggregates are a day of Brahmá, and fourteen Menus reign within that term.
> ...
> and the interval, called a **Manwantara, is equal to seventy-one times the number of years contained in the four Yugas**, with some additional years: this is the duration of the Manu, the (attendant) divinities, and the rest, **which is equal to 852,000 divine years, or to 306,720,000 years of mortals**, independent of the additional period.
>
> [Sanskrit verse and Hindi translation from Gitapress](https://archive.org/details/vishnu-puran-illustrated-with-hindi-translations-gita-press-gorakhpur/page/n18/mode/1up):
> [image]

Now, as per this

```
71 chaturyuga = 1 Manwantara 
71 chaturyuga = 306,720,000 human years
1 chaturyuga = 306,720,000 human years / 71 = 4,320,000 human years
1 chaturyuga i.e. Satya+Treta+Dwapara+Kali yuga = 4,320,000 human years
```

As we know (from first part of this answer) that ratio of Satya, Treta, Dwapara and Kali yugas is 4:3:2:1.

```
So, age of Kali Yuga = 1/(4+3+2+1) * 4,320,000 = 432,000 human years
```

---

Related:

- [Where has it said in the authentic scriptures, that a year in the Yuga schematic of Manu is actually a Daiva year?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/48960/where-has-it-said-in-the-authentic-scriptures-that-a-year-in-the-yuga-schematic/48961#48961)

Answer (score 2):

In Hinduism, the duration of Kali Yuga is believed to be 432,000 years. This belief is based on the scriptures, particularly the Srimad Bhagavatam and the Mahabharata.

The confusion about the duration of Kali Yuga arises from a misinterpretation of a verse in the Surya Siddhanta, an ancient Hindu text on astronomy. The verse states that Kali Yuga began when the sun and moon were in conjunction at the beginning of the lunar month of Kartik. Some scholars have interpreted this verse to mean that Kali Yuga began on the day of the conjunction, which occurred in 3102 BCE. Using the four yugas cycle of Satya, Treta, Dwapara, and Kali, they have calculated the duration of Kali Yuga to be 5,000 years. However, this interpretation is not supported by other Hindu texts and is considered to be a mistake.

The correct calculation of the duration of Kali Yuga is 432,000 years. This is based on the scriptures, which describe the duration of each of the four yugas in a descending order. Satya Yuga lasts for 1,728,000 years, Treta Yuga lasts for 1,296,000 years, Dwapara Yuga lasts for 864,000 years, and Kali Yuga lasts for 432,000 years. After the end of Kali Yuga, a new cycle of yugas begins with Satya Yuga.

It is important to note that the concept of yugas and their durations is a symbolic representation of the cyclical nature of time in Hinduism. The exact duration of each yuga may not be as important as the spiritual lessons that they convey.

The mention of the duration of Kali Yuga as 4,32,000 years can be found in the Mahabharata, Book 12, Shanti Parva, Section 231, Verse 8. Here's an English translation of the verse:

> "Eighteen yugas have passed away, and there are only two yugas now. O son of Kuru's race, those two are the Krita and the Kali. The duration of the Krita has been stated to be four thousand years and that of the Kali Yuga, only one thousand. The remaining period of time, constituting the difference between the Krita and the Yuga that comes next after it, is called a twilight by those that are well versed in ancient lore."

Comment: there is no mistake in surya siddhanta. kali yug did begin in 3102 BC, and currently we are 5000 years into it. doesn't mean entire duration is 5000. where is the confusion ?

Comment: @mar He used ChatGPT to answer questions.

Comment: Can you get rid of ChatGPT generated part ? And add your own words ?